# How to insert values into selected columns from c# coding?

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server

I have a table in SQL Server which has many columns. Now I want to add values only in selected columns, but when I do this it raised the exception like this:

> There are fewer columns in the INSERT statement than values specified
>   in the VALUES clause. The number of values in the VALUES clause must
>   match the number of columns specified in the INSERT statement.)

How to handle this?

This is my code:

```
SqlConnection con = getDbConnection();
SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("insert into pi_project_info(control#,pro_name,cust_name,cust_order,order_dt,req_dt,notes) values ('" + tb_control.Text + "','" + tb_project.Text + "','" + ddl_customer_name.Text + "','" + tb_order_no.Text + "','" + dp_order.Text + "','" + dp_order.Text + "','" + dp_req_del.Text + "','" + tb_notes.Text + "' )", con);

 cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
 MessageBox.Show("Saved successfully");
```

Comment: The error message really says it all (and very clearly): your column list in the `INSERT` statements lists **7 columns**, but the `VALUES()` collection has **8 values** - that doesn't work ... also: don't manually concatenate your SQL statement - instead use **parametrized queries** - **ALWAYS** (absolutely NO exceptions....)

Comment: you have mentioned 7 columns in your insert but passing 8 values

Comment: Yep, the columns and values must match-up, it's that simple... if some values are optional then you typically represent them as null values in the database (meaning value not specified for this row)... and one of the fun parts of database programming is working out how to map from data-entry-field values to null-database values. There's no one correct answer to this, as it depends on the requirements... but typically the empty string and zero are mapped to null (and vice-versa).

Comment: YHAKYOU SO MUCH MARC AND CODELGNOTO.. ANSWER APPRECIATED

Answer (score 1):

The error you got is pretty clear. The error messages never lie.

> Why I got this error?

Because you are inserting 8 values into 7 columns. The values must match the columns number listed in your `INSERT` statement.

> How to handle this?

Insert only 7 values into 7 columns. Or may be you are missing a column name in the columns list.

By the way, your code is *vulnerable* to [SQL injection](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection). Try to use parameterized query. See this article for more information:

- [**Preventing SQL Injection in ASP.NET**](http://www.mikesdotnetting.com/Article/113/Preventing-SQL-Injection-in-ASP.NET)

Answer (score 1):

You got a duplicate:

```
 dp_order.Text + "','" + dp_order.Text
```

Just drop one, then it works. But consider using Sql parameters to avoid SQL Injection